# How can I stop the Ubuntu Software Center from autostarting in Xubuntu?

Tags: software-center, xubuntu, autostart

I recently installed Xubuntu 11.10 and am completely updated. Software sources used include proposed as well as backports (in case that means anything).

My issue is that the Ubuntu software center autostarts on login. I've already checked my startup apps in 'session and startup' through the settings manager and it isn't set there. Is this just a 'deal with it' situation like Unity in Ubuntu? Or is there some glaringly obvious setting that I'm missing? Been considering installing 10.04 and just upgrading features a la carte to avoid 11.10 bugs. Any ideas?

Oh and there is no check in the save session box. USC is closed when I shut down anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In the XFCE settings, go to "Session and Startup"

In the general tab, unselect "Automatically save session on logout"

[image: Options]

Close the software center, log out and back in ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove previous saved session:

```
$ rm ~/.cache/sessions/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove previous saved session (with GUI):

[image]

**Press "Clear saved session"**