# How do I stop Gimp from autolaunching on startup?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, startup-applications, thunar, startupmanager

Gimp launches every time I log into Xubuntu (v. 13.10).

Gimp is not shown under Settings Manager-> Sessions and startup.

It does not appear in ~/.config/autostart.

I immediately close Gimp in these cases, so it is not running when I shut down the session.

How do I stop Gimp from autolaunching on startup?

---

**Diagnostic Info:**

Note that

```
cd /
find . -name gimp.desktop
```

Only produces

```
./usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop
```

and nothing else

Here is the output of  *grep -lIr 'gimp' ~/ > ~/Gimp-search-results.txt*

```
sbin/vgimportclone
home/joshua/.gimp-2.8/controllerrc
home/joshua/.gimp-2.8/tags.xml
```

.....[edited for brevity]

```
home/joshua/.cache/oneconf/861c4e30b916e750f16fab5652ed5937/package_list_861c4e30b916e750f16fab5652ed5937
    home/joshua/.cache/sessions/xfwm4-23e853443-fb4b-42fd-aa61-33fa99fdc12c.state
    home/joshua/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-athena:0
    home/joshua/.config/abiword/profile
```

Comment: have you tried to add it at the startup at any time? how did you implemented that? The possibilities of what is making the program tun are too many. It could be a script at system level, an entry on your bashrc, and everything between one and the other.

Comment: ok, raw approach: open a terminal and type locate gimp.desktop ...the results shouldn't be outside usr/share

Comment: Note that 

    
    find . -name gimp.desktop 

in base dir only produces

    ./usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop

and nothing else

Comment: Please run `grep -lIr 'gimp' ~/ > ~/Gimp-search-results.txt` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @Rho I edited the post to state where gimp.desktop is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it look like gimp is saved in your session cache.

```
.cache/sessions/xfwm4-23e853443-fb4b-42fd-aa61-33fa99fdc12c.state
.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-athena:0
```

Try this:

[image]

**Press "Clear saved session"**

Then be sure gimp is not open and restart.

Answer (score 2):

- In settings Manager-> Sessions and startup ,  try to activate "remember last session", then close Gimp and the session.
- At next login, it should be ok, so you can unselect "remember last session".

If still getting problems, look here  :
[How can I stop the Ubuntu Software Center from autostarting in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93049/how-can-i-stop-the-ubuntu-software-center-from-autostarting-in-xubuntu?rq=1)